# How to get the difference of a column between the most current date and the earliest date on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the columns for table `users`.

```
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid    | int(6) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| score  | decimal(6,2)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status | text            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date   | datetime        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cid    | int(7) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+--------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want the difference between a user's most current score and earliest score. I tried:

```
select co1.uid, co1.score, co1.date from users as co1, (select uid, score, min(date) from users group by uid) as co2 where co2.uid = co1.uid;
```

This does not work. I also tried

```
select co1.uid, co1.score, co1.date from users as co1, (select uid, score, max(date) - min(date) from users group by uid) as co2 where co2.uid = co1.uid;
```

Result I get:http://pastebin.com/seR81WbE

Result I want:

```
uid  max(score)-min(score)
1        40
2       -60
3        23
```

etc

Comment: Can you please post your current results and your desired results?  That would help out a lot.

Comment: I pasted it. The result I want is not actual data, it's just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is two `join`s:

```
select u.uid, umin.score, umax.score
from (select uid, min(date) as mind, max(date) as maxd
      from users
      group by uid
     ) u join
     users umin
     on u.uid = umin.uid and umin.date = u.mind join
     users umax
     on u.uid = umax.uid and umax.date = u.maxd;
```

I should note:  if you know the scores are only increasing, you can do the much simpler:

```
select uid, min(score), max(score)
from users
group by uid;
```

Comment: What is the meaning of umin.score, umax.score if this is MySQL?

Comment: @Pallas you are giving the table an alias.  Otherwise the query handler does not know which `users` table of the 2 did you mean. So when you say `join users umin` you are referring to that table as `umin` for this query.

Comment: Was I also suppose to include u.date in the first select since the db is saying `Unknown column 'u.date' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @Pallas . . . Ooops, got the aliases backwards.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! This seems to work. I forgot to mention though, that some scores are null. How would I modify this to select the most current not-null score and the earliest not-null score?

Comment: You would add `where score is not null` to the subquery.